# Real-time updates on specific fields Cloud Firestore documents

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to add a listener to a specific field in a document on firebase firestore instead of adding a listener to the whole document?

Example:

Document contains multiple string attributes such as names, contact information, position and I want to get real time updates for position only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firestore listeners fire on the document level. There is no way to get triggered with just specific fields in a document.

If you want to get notified only of specific fields, consider adding an extra collection with documents that only contain those fields. This sort of data duplication is quite common in NoSQL solutions such as Firestore.

Comment: You can also use firebase realtime database for those fields and the rest keep them in firestore.